# Big query query is too complex after pivot

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

Assume I have the following table `table` and a list of interests `(cat, dog, music, soccer, coding)`

```
|   userId | user_interest  |  label   |
| -------- | -------------- |----------|
| 12345    | cat            |    1     |
| 12345    | dog            |    1     | 
| 6789     | music          |    1     |
| 6789     | soccer         |    1     |
```

I want to transform the user interest into a binary array (i.e. binarization), and the resulting table will be something like

```
|   userId | labels         |  
| -------- | -------------- |
| 12345    | [1,1,0,0,0]    |   
| 6789     | [0,0,1,1,0]    |
```

I am able to do it with `PIVOT` and `ARRAY`, e.g.

```
WITH user_interest_pivot AS (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM (
        SELECT userId, user_interest, label FROM table
          ) AS T
      PIVOT
      (
           MAX(label) FOR user_interestc IN  ('cat', 'dog', 'music', 'soccer', 'coding') 
 
      ) AS P
)

  SELECT
    userId,
    ARRAY[IFNULL(cat,0), IFNULL(dog,0), IFNULL(music,0), IFNULL(soccer,0), IFNULL(coding,0)] AS labels,
  FROM user_interea_pivot
```

HOWEVER, in reality I have a very long list of interests, and the above method in bigquery seems to not work due to

> 

Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too comple

> 

Please help to let me know if there is anything I can do to deal with this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still it's likely to face resource problem depending on your real data, but it is worth trying the following approach without PIVOT.

1. Create **interests** table with additional index column first

```
+----------+-----+-----------------+
| interest | idx | total_interests |
+----------+-----+-----------------+
| cat      |   0 |               5 |
| dog      |   1 |               5 |
| music    |   2 |               5 |
| soccer   |   3 |               5 |
| coding   |   4 |               5 |
+----------+-----+-----------------+
```

2. find **idx** of each user interest and aggreage them like below. (assuming that user intererest is sparse over overall interests)

```sql
    SELECT userId, ARRAY_AGG(idx) user_interests
      FROM sample_table t JOIN interests i ON t.user_interest = i.interest
     GROUP BY 1
```

3. Lastly, create **labels** vector using a sparse user interest array and dimension of interest space (i.e. **total_interests**) like below

```
       ARRAY(SELECT IF(ui IS NULL, 0, 1)
               FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, total_interests - 1)) i
               LEFT JOIN t.user_interests ui ON i = ui
              ORDER BY i
       ) AS labels
```

##### Query

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT '12345' AS userId, 'cat' AS user_interest, 1 AS label UNION ALL
SELECT '12345' AS userId, 'dog' AS user_interest, 1 AS label UNION ALL
SELECT '6789' AS userId, 'music' AS user_interest, 1 AS label UNION ALL
SELECT '6789' AS userId, 'soccer' AS user_interest, 1 AS label;

CREATE TEMP TABLE interests AS 
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER () AS total_interests 
    FROM UNNEST(['cat', 'dog', 'music', 'soccer', 'coding']) interest 
    WITH OFFSET idx
;

SELECT userId,
       ARRAY(SELECT IF(ui IS NULL, 0, 1)
               FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, total_interests - 1)) i
               LEFT JOIN t.user_interests ui ON i = ui
              ORDER BY i
       ) AS labels
  FROM (
    SELECT userId, total_interests, ARRAY_AGG(idx) user_interests
      FROM sample_table t JOIN interests i ON t.user_interest = i.interest
     GROUP BY 1, 2
  ) t;
```

##### Query results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think below approach will "survive" any [reasonable] data

```
create temp function base10to2(x float64) returns string 
language js as r'return x.toString(2);';
with your_table as (
  select '12345' as userid, 'cat' as user_interest, 1 as label union all
  select '12345' as userid, 'dog' as user_interest, 1 as label union all
  select '6789' as userid, 'music' as user_interest, 1 as label union all
  select '6789' as userid, 'soccer' as user_interest, 1 as label
), interests as ( 
  select *, pow(2, offset) weight, max(offset + 1) over() as len
    from unnest(['cat', 'dog', 'music', 'soccer', 'coding']) user_interest 
    with offset
)
select userid, 
  split(rpad(reverse(base10to2(sum(weight))), any_value(len), '0'), '') labels, 
from your_table
join interests 
using(user_interest)
group by userid
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This is very awesome. one thing I have a concern about this approach is that due to rounding error of floating point number, it may return invalid results. i.e.  [1, 3, 30, 54]  of user interests from GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 55) total interests will return only three **1** if I didn't test it wrong.

Comment: @Jaytiger - i think this is **false alarm** - i just tested and both `30` and `54` returns correct binary representation  - respectively -  `011110` and `011011` (obviously in reverse order as it is to meet question's requirements)

Comment: kindly check what I've tested and it's result in another answer.

Comment: oh, i read your initial comment wrongly! i see now what you mean. Thank you for pointing! yes agree. interesting to investigate why exactly this happens ... i feel i know why but need play more around it. meantime looks like it still should work for up to **53 distinct interests** :o)

Comment: Yes, it still seems to work nicely under around 50 digits. As always, thanks for sharing your wonderful knowledge.